# Safety from SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, sql-injection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techconn"].ToString());

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from hs where ac between'" + TextBox1.Text + "'and '" + TextBox2.Text + "' and em='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "'", con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.Visible = false;
            }

            con.Close();
```

Is this code safe from SQL injection?

If not, please correct this code that it is safe from SQL injection.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: No, it is not safe. You need to do some research on *SQL Parameters*.

Comment: @AndrewMorton please corrcet this code

Comment: This is a textbook example of code that IS vulnerable to injection.

Comment: This is not a "write my code for me" site. You have to make some effort. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the answer is no.  You need to always use parameters in your queries.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from hs where ac between @ac1 and @ac2 and em=@em", con);
```

You then add the parameters to your SqlCommand object (com).

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is quite prone to issues, not only sql injection attacks. Try the following:

```
    public DataTable GetData(string textbox1, string textbox2, string dropdown)
    {
        DataTable result = null;
        string connString = null;

        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techconn"] != null)
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techconn"].ConnectionString;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connString))
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from hs where (ac between @a and @b) and em = @c";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textbox1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", textbox2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", dropdown);

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    result = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(result);

                }
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Paste it in your code and use by

```
DataTable dt = GetData(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.Visible = false;
            }
```

Test it properly too.

Answer (score 0):

IF you use direct textbox reference to your sql query then it will never be SQL injection safe any end user can pass Injecting values to your text box and it will be injected.

Never use UI elements directly to your SQL you can try the below line of CODE

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);  
conn.Open();  
string s = "select * from hs where ac between @TextBoxOnevaluevariable and
@TextBoxTwovaluevariable and em=@DropdownSelectedTextVariable";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextBoxOnevaluevariable", Texbox1.Text);  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextBoxTwovaluevariable", Texbox2.Text);  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DropdownSelectedTextVariable",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());  
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```